# SD cards electrical specification

Tags: voltage, current, embedded, sd, soc

I designed a -very simple- circuit powered by a 12V battery.
I would like to add a sd card connector (its type is of no importance right now) on that circuit.

But I am concerned by the datasheets I find on the net:

- [first](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1673781.pdf). No operation voltage?
- [second](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1683662.pdf). How could I possibly feed a huge 250VAC RMS with my circuit?
- [third](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1636988.pdf). 100 VAC max is approx 70V DC (100 * 2sq2). Way too much as well.
- [fourth](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/276/5025700893_MEMORY_CARD_SOCKET-179363.pdf). According to Ohm's law, I could put a 24 ohms resistor and be good.

I am pretty sure I miss something because one find those in every SoCs.

Could we make those fit my circuit anyway? (how?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the feeling that you do not understand these datesheets.

That 250 VAC is what the connector **can survive without getting damaged**. It does not mean that it needs 250 VAC to work !

Not even going into your 70V remark (too irrelevant).

An SD card connector takes an SD card and connects it to a chip (that could be a SoC) with an SD card interface. That's it. You need to **think about what a connector does**. It connects, that is it.

So just pick a connector that fits your needs (size wise and price wise), ignore the electrical specs as it does not matter.

Comment: 70V => Actually it it 100 * .636 = 63.6V, right?

Comment: It is not clear to me what your interest in this 100 VAC is. 100 VAC is **a lot** more than any SD card or SD card interface on a chip can handle. 100VAC RMS has a peak voltage of 141 V maybe that is what you mean. But anyway, it is irrelevant.